# Listing all possible solutions Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am a beginner for prolog and
I want to list all possible solution for all variables for example :

```
  word(V1,V2,V3) :- some code
```

I want all possible values for `V1` to `V3`,
so instead of returning

```
?-word(V1,V2,V3).
V1 = x1,
V2 = x2,
V3 = x3;
V1 = y1,
V2 = y2,
V3 = y3.
```

it return

```
V1 = [x1, y1]
V2 = [x2, y2]
V3 = [x3, y3]
```

I tried findall but i get an error I don't know how to use it for this example.

Comment: Please note that variables have to start with a capital letter.

Comment: yes i know that i just write it here with lowercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`findall/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3)to collect all solutions in a list of lists. For example, considering the program:

```
word(x1, x2, x3).
word(y1, y2, y3).
```

You get the following result:

```
?- findall([V1,V2,V3], word(V1,V2,V3), M).
M = [[x1, x2, x3], [y1, y2, y3]].
```

The list `M`obtained can be viewed as the **matrix**:

```
M = [[x1, x2, x3], 
     [y1, y2, y3]].
```

However, the answer you want is the corresponding **transposed matrix**:

```
T = [[x1, y1],
     [x2, y2],
     [x3, y3]].
```

To transpose matrix `M`, you can combine `findall/3`, [`maplist/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3)and  [`nth1/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth1/3) as following:

```
?- M = [[x1,x2,x3], [y1,y2,y3]], findall(L, maplist(nth1(_), M, L), T).
M = [[x1, x2, x3], [y1, y2, y3]],
T = [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]].
```

Thus, the **final code** to solve your problem is:

```
words(V1, V2, V3) :-
   findall([V1,V2,V3], word(V1,V2,V3), M),
   findall(L, maplist(nth1(_), M, L), [V1,V2,V3]).

word(x1, x2, x3).
word(y1, y2, y3).
```

Example:

```
?- words(V1,V2,V3).
V1 = [x1, y1],
V2 = [x2, y2],
V3 = [x3, y3].
```